# Workflow change of creator

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

There is a workflow created by an ex-employee and I need to change the creator making it the system admin instead of employee.
Any ideas how can I change this without causing further implications on the workflow process?

I came up with exporting that exact workflow and import it back on the same existing workflow but I am afraid that it might cause implications.

Comment: Are you working with SPonline?

Comment: yes I use online SharePoint

Comment: Do you use FLOW or classic SP workflow (that you can edit in SharePoint designer)

Comment: We use Nintex workflow designer

Comment: I haven't been working with Nintex for Sharepoint online but probably best if you ask that question on Nintex forum.